# Ionic 2 Google FCM push notification icon

Tags: node.js, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

Im having some kind of trouble setting my Ionic's icon when I send a push notification through FCM. My notification looks like:

```
var mensaje = {
  "notification":{
    "title": "Some title",
    "body":"Body",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon": "?????"
  },
  "data":{
    "title": "Title",
    "url": "url"
  }
};
```

In the ionic app into resources folder I have an logo.png that's the one that I want to use for the notification. What route or string should I send to this image to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

First of all put the `logo.png` into a `drawable` folder and put this folder into your `platforms/android/res/` folder if you are building for android.

Once this is done, in the app project, in the code where you initialize the notification place the name of the file **without the extension**.

Like below:

```
const pushObj: PushObject = this.push.init({
                        android: {
                            senderID: "your_gcm_id",                                
                            icon: "logo",
                            forceShow: "true"
                        },
                        ios: {
                            alert: "true",
                            badge: "true",
                            sound: "true"
                        }
                    });
```

Now in the server side code also in the place of icon, put the name `logo`.

Everything should work fine now.